# Change Extrude Amount textGeometry Three.js

Tags: three.js

I've added text to my scene using the code from https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/TextGeometry

I cannot figure out how to change the extrude depth, which is much "thicker" than I would like. Here is the exact code I am using:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'fonts/font.json', function ( font ) {
var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'WELCOME', {
    font: font,
    size: 4,
    height: 8,
    amount: 8,//attempt to change the depth but doesn't work
} );
```

Is it possible to change the extrude amount for a text geometry?

Comment: The [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/TextGeometry) says: _height — Float. Thickness to extrude text. Default is 50._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `height` and `amount` at the same time does not work. `amount` is an option for `ExtrudeGeometry` whereas `height` is intended for `TextGeometry`.

`TextGeometry` uses internally `ExtrudeGeometry` for geometry generation. In this context, `height` is mapped to `amount`.

three.js R92